# Shortkey or Script that can select block of code

Tags: ide, ssms, autohotkey, text-editor, hotkeys

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and there are 5-10 lines of queries that I edit and execute a lot. I'm wondering whether there is a way that can quickly select a block of code? The code could start and end with some key words. For example:

```
--Start 

 line1
 line2

--end
```

I searched the shortcut key webpage for Sql management studio and didn't find a quick solution.

The solution could either be a keyboard shortcut or some automatic script like autohotkey. A generic solution works with general text/code editor would be the best, since I also works with R/MATLAB and wondering whether there is a generic solution for selecting code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, general, autohotkey solution, working with notepad, bound to `ctrl+b` for testing purposes, do edit accordingly.

```
^b::
    selectBlock(){
        clipbackup:=clipboard
        clipboard:=
        Send ^a^c
        ClipWait
        Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
        {
            if (SubStr(A_LoopField,1,7)="--Start")
                s:=A_Index
            if (s and SubStr(A_LoopField,1,5)="--end"){
                e:=A_Index-1
                break
            }
        }
        if (s and e)
            Send % "^{Home}{Down " s "}{Shift Down}{Down " e-s "}{Shift Up}"
        else
            Send {Left}
        clipboard:=clipbackup
    }
return
```

Side note, I'm not familiar with your software but I find it hard to imagine there are no better ways of doing it. For example using built in search tool that might even support regex as most "text editors" aimed at "coding" have. Or adopting above code to work with "go to X line" function of your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll test it. Now I'm actually using the regex solution, and the expression I use is --start((.|\n)*)--end.

Comment: I tested your solution and it works well! It's a bit slow when a lot of lines involved, but it's good enough for me now. Thanks a lot for your help!